# Query cache in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, caching

Is there any mechanism to keep query results in order to reuse them the next time this query occurs?
I'm not talking about SQLite's cache that stores pages retrieved from a database file.
This is more about a query execution without using SQLite B-tree and Pager modules.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Statement cache then SQLite does not provide statement cache feature.

You create your own cache after executing your query using C syntax to maintain array of `sqlite_stmt*`